# Livewire WithFileUpload 401 with url's not matching so failing signature check

Tags: file-upload, signature, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire file uploader on a project. When you select a file it says `The uploads failed to upload.` The firefox dev toolbox says it is a 401 error. I investigated further and found via https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1216 that commenting out a line in the livewire vendor src (`abort_unless(request()->hasValidSignature(), 401);`) actually doesn't show this message and allows the file to upload but this is obviously extremely bad practice for mulitple reasons (update of livewire will undo change, it removes csrf protection and as it's in the vendor folder it is not in my repo).

I decided instead to step into how this is working and found it is creating a malformed url. This is in the laravel framework /Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator: line 413 [hasCorrectSignature]

```
    /**
     * Determine if the signature from the given request matches the URL.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @param  array  $ignoreQuery
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasCorrectSignature(Request $request, $absolute = true, array $ignoreQuery = [])
    {
        $ignoreQuery[] = 'signature';

        $url = $absolute ? $request->url() : '/'.$request->path();

        $queryString = collect(explode('&', (string) $request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')))
            ->reject(fn ($parameter) => in_array(Str::before($parameter, '='), $ignoreQuery))
            ->join('&');

        $original = rtrim($url.'?'.$queryString, '?');

        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $original, call_user_func($this->keyResolver));

        return hash_equals($signature, (string) $request->query('signature', ''));
    }
```

As I step over this function with Xdebug I get the following variables

```
$url = "https://my-project.dev/livewire/upload-file"
$queryString = "/livewire/upload-file&expires=1674038186"
$original = "https://my-project.dev/livewire/upload-file?/livewire/upload-file&expires=1674038186" <- note this is malformed right?
```

signature this makes is

```
fc95677fc265d9ad90e0ff5413eecf5cb08df82b3971b468109e1011fc323406
```

And lastly the signature created from the query is

```
6152b1a0c51c2e7532d2665bf3f2cf3a809802689185b0c5d73e2854024de124
```

So these do not match and thus it fails, I suspect that the signature of the correct url will match the 2nd signature (i.e. signature for `https://my-project.dev/livewire/upload-file&expires=1674038186`). So how do I ensure this url is correct.

I've noticed a more than likely related issue with url's when I login the app after being auto logged out so if i was on a page `https://my-project.dev/foo/bar` then after logging back in it is now `https://my-project.dev/foo/bar?%2Ffoo%2Fbar=` This has no impact on the page that is generated.

My `.htaccess` in the public folder is:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has this issue I had an overnight epithany and realised that the issue is the wildcard in the htaccess RewriteRule. Remove the ? and everything works correctly. It also fixed the odd url issue I was getting.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```